# How can I show localized category-titles of an extbase-object, when the objects sys_language_uid=-1

Tags: localization, typo3, extbase

I have a TYPO3 9.5 site with two languages, german has the sys_language_uid=0 (english: 1).
There are many categorized objects (articles) set for all languages, i.e sys_language_uid=-1.
Problem: The attached categories, which are completely localized the TYPO3-backend, which are resolved via getCategories() are shown in german on the english frontend.
It seems that the attached children of an object with sys_language_uid=-1 are not localized to the pages' language.
Is this a feature by design or a bug or is there a misconfiguration?